# Thicken a one pixel line

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV to do some image processing on Python. I'm trying to overlay an outline on an image where the outline was made from a mask. I'm using `cv2.Canny()` to get the outline of the mask, then changing that to a color using `cv2.cvtColor()` then finally converting that edge to cyan using `outline[np.where((outline == [255,255,255]).all(axis=2))] = [180,105,255]`. My issue now is that this is a one pixel thick line and can barely be seen on large images. This outline is all `[0,0,0]` except on the points I apply as a mask onto my color image using `cv2.bitwise_or(img, outline`.

I'm currently thickening this outline by brute forcing and checking every single pixel in the bitmap to check if any of its neighbors are [180,105,255] and if so, that pixel will also change. This is very slow. Is there any way using numpy or openCV to do this automatically? I was hoping for some conditional indexing with numpy, but can't find anything.

Comment: Did you try dilating the outline?

Comment: No, I didn't know that existed. How would I use that?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html

Comment: or with OpenCV: `dilated = cv2.dilate(im, np.ones((3, 3)))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two methods depending on the situation:

- [`cv2.dilate()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) - enhance all white pixels
- [`cv2.drawContours()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html) - enhance specific pixels

---

**Example**

Using this input image

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create test image
mask = np.zeros((200,200,3), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.line(mask, (50, 100), (150, 100), (255,255,255), 1)
```

**Method #1**

All pixels in the foreground (white) will have its area increased with `cv2.dilate()`. We create a [structuring element](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) and dilate. More iterations will generate a thicker line

`iterations=1` (left), `iterations=2` (middle), `iterations=3` (right)

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
```

**Method #2**

When we want to only enhance a particular part of an image but leave other sections untouched, we can use `cv2.drawContours()`. We can specify the color and adjust the size using the `thickness` parameter. The result will be similar to `cv2.dilate()` with the added benefit of color selection

[image]

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), thickness=15)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at morphological operations.  Dilation sounds closest to what you want.  You might need to work on a subregion with your line if you don't want to dilate the rest of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a [dilation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga4ff0f3318642c4f469d0e11f242f3b6c). A dilation is a *morphological operation* which causes brighter regions within the input image to grow. As explained [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html), dilation is performed by convoluting the input image with some *kernel*:

> As the kernel B is scanned over the image, we compute the maximal
>   pixel value overlapped by B and replace the image pixel in the anchor
>   point position with that maximal value.

The *anchor point* is usually the center of the kernel.

In your case, I would suggest using an *elliptical kernel* with a size of your choice. With one pixel thick lines and with a *kernel* of size `(n,n)`, the lines in your resulting dilated image will be approximately `2*n` thick.

Here's a sample code :

```
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
    result = cv2.dilate(outline, kernel)
```

Here is an example of dilation :

[image]